# Pattern matching for properties in a Java-based Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, spring-java-config

Is it possible to inject a list of properties matching a specific reg exp pattern from Java-based Spring 4 configuration file.

For example given a property file that contains:

```
prefix.prop1=value1
prefix.prop2=value2
prefix.prop3=value3
other.property=someothervalue
```

Ideally something I would like to inject the prefix.* properties into a bean - as a map for example.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration{

    public valueMap(@Value(?prefix.*?) Map<String, String> propertyMap) {

        //where propertyMap would contain key/values : 
        //prop1, value1 ; prop2, value2 ; prop3, value3

    }
}
```

I've been looking at Spring EL expressions with no success also at customizing the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. 
Ideally I don't want to read the file again and process it again if Spring can do it for me.

Comment: You can do it in Spring Boot - see [21.6 Typesafe Configuration Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround:

Extend `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and add a method which gives you the result of `mergeProperties()`.

You can then inject this new bean into your `AppConfiguration`, iterate over the properties and filter those with the prefix you want.